# flutter gradle build failed with gradle 4.2.2 and sdk version 31

Tags: java, android, flutter, maven, gradle

I get below error when building flutter mobile apps:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location_permissions:parseReleaseLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':location_permissions:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\zukijuki\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\zukijuki\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar
```

my `android/build.gradle` conf:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'        
    }
}
```

and below `app/build.gradle`:

```
...

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        //disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "en", "US"
    }
    
    ...

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"){ force = true } 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'


}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

any idea to fix the above problem?

Thank you in advance...

===**update**

1. gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

2. Build using `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3`
3. Reinstall API Level 29,30,31,32 still cant resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve this issue by downgrade my Gradle version to `4.1.0`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        ...        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some configuration files for android are missing.

Try reinstalling the Android SDK.

To do this, you need to uninstall from SDK Manager and then reinstall it.

Find it by: Clicking Tools > SDK Manager.

Comment: Hi, I have added it before

Comment: Which IDE are you building from?

Comment: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 17, 2022

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer now that I know this.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling SDK 29,30,31 but nothing change